# How to send a tag or data to OneSignal using Flutter

Tags: notifications, flutter, tags, push, onesignal

I am trying to send data or a tag to OneSignal using Flutter. It seems like I can send push notification using PlayerID. But one device can only have 1 PlayerID. So, I am trying to send data to onesignal, so that I can use the data for sending the notifications.